# NSSegmentControl Images Scaling Not Working

Tags: macos, cocoa, nssegmentedcontrol

The problem appears specifically when using an NSSegmentControl and in the segments inside images are placed (set via StoryBoard). Furthermore it only happens when using a Retina MacBook and if you're NOT connected to a second monitor.

When the above conditions are met the images render at larger sizes than they should. You can reproduce the problem by creating a new Project in XCode, dropping an NSSegmentControl in its ToolBar and then adding an image, like "NSBonjour"  or "NSCaution". It does not happen for some other images like "NSStatusNone"

I believe this may be a bug, problem is I'm not entirely sure and how can I fix this in my app. I have no idea and found no information online.

Any help appreciated,

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem, apparently images in segmented control must have different image sizes vs. normal buttons.

They should be:

19x19 at 1x
38x38 at 2x
57x57 at 3x

Hope this helps future devs.

Regards,

Marc